# How to get ids of the objects from django model?

Tags: python, django

How to get ids of the objects from the model.

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
cityID = City.objects.get(pk=1)
```

The above query will return only one object whose id is `1`. but I need all cities `id` so that can I access the city's names from `id` as you can see in below code.

```
for s in qs:
...     s_name = qs.filter(name__iendswith=cityID.name)
...     break
```

**Added:** model society and city

```
class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    locality = models.ForeignKey('Locality', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='localityId', blank=True, null=True, related_name='society_set')  # Field name made lowercase.
    dot_com_database_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='dotComDatabaseId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'societies'

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='updatedAt', auto_now=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    connect_database_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='connectDatabaseId', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dot_com_database_name = models.CharField(db_column='dotComDatabaseName', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location_master_request_url = models.CharField(db_column='locationMasterRequestUrl', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='countryId', blank=True, null=True, related_name='city_set')  # Field name made lowercase.
    pms_operation_status = models.CharField(db_column='pmsOperationStatus', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cities'
```

Comment: Can you please show the City and Society model code

Comment: @Thierno Amadou Sow
Yes, because I want to get each name by its id and compare it with society's name. As you can see in for loop.

Comment: this `cityID = City.objects.values_list('pk',flat=True)` will give you all cities's id,

Comment: @rahul.m
Yes of course, check I have added

Comment: @Thierno Amadou Sow
Thanks for your answer, So how can I add this to for loop as mentioned above in the post? Because when I'm adding this throws me an error: `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: @AkashSingh Could you describe what you want. Maybe It has another way.

Comment: @Javohir Elmurodov
Thanks for asking, So I want to get the city name to check if there is any society name containing the city name at the end of the society name. I have tried to get names using this `City.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)` but it didn't help me. For more details, you can check my previous posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377088/how-can-i-check-my-society-models-name-contains-citys-id-or-not and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333550/how-can-i-check-that-societies-name-contain-city-or-locality-name-and-update-the

Comment: @Thierno Amadou Sow
 This query is getting all city's id `cityID = City.objects.values_list('pk',flat=True)` but I can't access city name by `id`. I want to access the city name by its `id` so I can check it with the society name.

Comment: From previous question, You wanna update Society title to without city name that end with City name. Is it right?

Comment: @Javohir Elmurodov
Yes, what do you think that I should use to update the society name and save it. Because I don't know how to use `update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
data = []
for name in citys:
    response = qs.filter(name__iendswith=name)
    if response.exists():
        data.append(response)
print(data)
```

Or You can do something like this (i will recommend this)

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce

qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
clauses = (Q(name__iendswith=name) for name in citys)
query = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
data = qs.filter(query)
```

Comment: Yes this is working but it also prints `<QuerySet []>` for those cities which are not in society's name. There is any way to skip those city names which are not in society's name and only prints society name that containg city name.

Comment: @AkashSingh i have update my answer and try it.

Comment: one more doubt you can help me with it. I also want to remove the city name from the society name and save it into the database. How can I do this? I used `remove` and `update` but I didn't find any solution. please help me.

Comment: @AkashSingh could you please ask an other question separately and explain your problem i will try to help you if i can.explain it explicitly i am not good in english.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
qs = Society.objects.all()
citys = City.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
qs = qs.filter(name__endswith=list(citys))
```

Comment: this returning me this `<QuerySet []>`